# Comparing row-wise DATES and substituting the values with 1 or 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have one column to compare with other 100 columns. The columns I need to compare are all **DATETIME**
The problem statement is as follows:

1. If the date in the "UTIL_DATE" is greater than equal to the date in other columns, substitute that row's value to 1
2. Else, 0

I have attached an example image below for the reference.

**For example:**
Since UTIL_DATE "31-12-2021" is greater than "23-09-2021", then we change the row value in column "Col3" to 1.
Since there is NaT in Col1, Col2 (and so one), those specific cannot be compared with UTIL_DATE. Hence, 0.

And the same thing iterate over for all the other rows

**CURRENTLY**
[image]

**EXPECTED**
[image]

I have tried a *try-except* loop. However, it is taking more than 1 hour 30 mins. I need to improve the performance.

Attached the code snippet for your reference:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows(): # row is each row in df and idx is the index for each row
    for i in format_cols: # format_cols is the list of columns to be compared with the UTIL_DATE column

        ifor_val = 0 # taking ifor_val as 0 by default

        try:
            if (pd.to_datetime(row["Util_Date"]) >= pd.to_datetime(row[i])): 
                ifor_val = 1 # if Util_Date >= column "i" date, then map it to 1. Else 0
 
        except:
            ifor_val = 0
        df.loc[idx,i]=ifor_val
```

Comment: add a reproducible example: run `df.to_dict()` and attach here the output to let other users reproduce your Dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this:

```
df=df.set_index('UTIL_DATE')
df=df.ge(df.index, axis=0)
df=df.replace({True:1,False:0})
```